# Variable not expanding in Perl string?

Tags: string, perl

i am trying to copy a png file using the next code

```
$cty2 = 'filename';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$old = 'images/bg_freeze.png';
$new = 'images/$cty2.png';
copy($old, $new) or die("Unable to copy $old to $new.");
fclose($fh);
```

But, the result is a png file with this name ( **$cty2.png** )
it should be ( **filename.png** )

How I solve it to make the new file name ( **filename.png** ) not ( **$cty2.png** )

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: I have edited as Perl-related (jumped the gun :-/), please correct if in error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't specified which language.  But the problem is almost certainly that you need to use double-quotes (`"`), not single-quotes (`'`).  Otherwise variables will not be expanded inside the string.

Comment: $old = "images/bg_freeze.png";
$new = "images/$cty2.png";